# Notification Engine based by kafka to sending push notification get the id from different users in android apps

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, apache-kafka

I am designing a Notification Engine (typescript Based) which will be used as an one stop shop for various other systems to send notification to different channels (push notifications, SMS, email etc). I wish to build this system to use Kafka as a message broker component (there will be many other components as well).

My query is specific to app push notifications (our current system uses FCM topic based subscribed notifications coming from individual systems who publish). The New Notification Engine will be working as the Kafka Producer and publish messages in regular intervals ( as configured in the Scheduler Component of this system) to the topics. How do the app user get the notifications as soon as they are published ? I am assuming the apps here have to work as Kafka Consumer. What is the best way to achieve this ? Is Kafka REST Proxy an option for the Mobile Apps to act like Kafka Consumers ? Would it be overload for mobile app to handle all the consumer responsibility ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn’t make the mobile app a consumer for 2 reasons

1. Security - you will need to save creds at client side
2. scaleability - every mobile would act as a consumer which will make the throughput of the topic to grow as the number of users grows

I would suggest you to write a new component that consumes that messages from kafka and publishes through socket data to the mobile clients.

Take a look at socket.io, supports typescript and also a easy to use library.

Good luck!